# Loopback Simulate a call to a remote method

Tags: node.js, socket.io, loopbackjs

Is it possible to simulate a call to a remote method in loopback?

I am using socket.io and I would like to make it possible for the client to emit an object containing a token and make the server respond by emitting the result of a remote method as if it was called by a real get request containing the token.

For example, if on the client side we do

```
mySocket.emit("getUsers",{token:"123456"});
```

I would like the server to respond by

```
SimulateCall("GET","api/users?access_token="+token , function(err,result){
    socket.emit("users",result)
})
```

SimulateCall fires a callback with the response that the server would give to a GET call to "/api/users?123456".

Is there some function that behaves like the SimulateCall method? If not , how can I implement it? Or maybe there is a better to do this?

Comment: basically you need to listen for  "getUsers" event on server side using socket.on('getUsers',function(data){}), and "users" event on client side i.e mySocket.on("users",function(result){}).

Comment: Yeah, that's obvious ;-) . My question is about how to implement the SimulateCall method though.

Comment: Use the `Request` module to trigger the call

Comment: @richardpringle I believe that that would not simulate a GET call, but actually do a real GET call. I was hoping to speed my webapp up by doing all the http request to my API via a socket. I don't believe that doing it the way you suggest would bring any speedup? Or maybe it would, im not sure

Comment: hmm I'm not sure about increasing the speed... but each CRUD operation comes with an associated function. `GET /api/Users` is the equivalent of calling `User.find(function(err, result) {})`. In this case you're ignoring the middleware chain though (and thus ignoring authorization).

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping for a way to "activate" the middleware with a fake request or something. But I don't have much experience with express, so I don't know if this is possible.